# Django RESTful API - django-piston vs. django-tastypie

Tags: django, api, django-piston

We're looking for a general RESTful API solution for our Django project. We would use the API at first for Ajax calls on the web site and later for mobile apps, external apps and things like that.

I found two modules which seem to be widely used. [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) and [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie)

From what I read, piston seems to be older and thus more mature but maybe a bit outdated?! 
While tastypie is relatively new and nicely documented.

What would be the best thing to go with? **django-piston** or **django-tastypie**?
Important for us (ordered by priority): Continuous maintenance of the source, documentation, stability, ease of use.

**EDIT (2013 Jul 16th):**

Now over a year later we have a clear winner. At first we went with tastypie. Which we kinda liked. But after half a year or so we switched to the then upcoming [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework) and never looked back.

What we like most about it:

- Nice documentation
- Active community
- Clean design (build upon django's class based views)
- Browsable API for development and debugging

We rely on the API heavily so support (in the future) is one of our main concerns. We met the maintainer - Tom Christie - (on and offline) and he seems very committed to the project. So we feel very comfortable using the django-rest-framework.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A good resource to compare them is http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/api/

Django-tastypie sure is the save choice right now.

Personally I'd advocate a look at [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) if you use django 1.3, because it uses the new class based views. djangopackages.com's comparison page shows it has good participation and activity. And, wow, it sure has a [nice browsable interface](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/) to the API.

Answer (score 24):

I have no experience with this, but I trust Pydanny in this:

> django-piston has been barely supported for nearly two years. That is
>   an eternity, and the number of forks to address multiple issues is a
>   cause for alarm. Because of that, in it's place at this time I
>   recommend django-tastypie. It is up-to-date, has very good
>   documentation, supports OAUTH, and scored second place in the Django
>   Packages thunderdome (it got nearly 3x as many points!). Another tool
>   to consider is Django Rest Framework, which is as good as
>   django-tastypie but lacks the OAUTH support.
>
> On the django-piston front, Joshua Ginsberg has taken over the reins
>   and we should hopefully see some movement again. In which case I'll be
>   able to remove this section of the blog post.

from Pydanny's [blog](http://pydanny.blogspot.com/2010/07/getting-piston-forms-to-play-nicely.html).

Comment: Update from Pydanny's blog: http://pydanny.com/choosing-an-api-framework-for-django.html . Summary: django-piston is dead, long live tastypie and django-rest-framework .

Answer (score 18):

Having implemented API's with django Piston, tastypie and [django webmachine](https://github.com/benoitc/dj-webmachine) Django tastypie rocks! Having said that, I think that while tastypie is really good when your API is modelled close to your models, it's a little bit more complicated to do things once you want to move out of the box. There are workarounds to some [issues](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/18#issuecomment-2695447), with others you have to do more bending than building. It will, probably, still cover 90% of django use cases.

Afaik Webmachine was modelled after the popular erlang webmachine, but hasn't been very active lately. So that leaves piston, which is picking up some activity, and tastypie, that has a lot of momentum and activity. Piston is a bit more flexible, but tastypie is moving very fast and in my opinion has a really easy API.

My recommendation would be to quicky implement a prototype of the API in tastypie, and see if it covers what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

[Django REST framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) 2.0 was [anounced in Oct 2012](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/rest-framework-2-announcement/) and now supports [OAuth](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#oauthauthentication) out of the box. What I really like is the [Web browseable API](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/), which is really helpful when developing your API, but also when someone implements your API. It's kind of comparable with using the Django admin site for inspecting your models' structure and data, but then for your API. Also the documentation is very good.

From their website:

> Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit that makes it
>   easy to build Web APIs.
>
> Some reasons you might want to use REST framework:
>
> - The Web browseable API is a huge usability win for your developers.
> - Authentication policies including OAuth1a and OAuth2 out of the box.
> - Serialization that supports both ORM and non-ORM data sources.
> - Customizable all the way down - just use regular function-based views if you don't need the more powerful features.
> - Extensive documentation, and great community support.

Check out their [Quickstart](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) guide to get a quick idea of how it works.