# Ajax implementation with Django

Tags: ajax, django

I am presently working on a Django project that requires the implementation of Ajax.
e.g adding model objects to the database, getting and updating model instances from the database etc without refreshing the page at all.
I have searched everywhere but am yet to come across any relevant material.
**I would implore the gurus in the house to point me in the direction of materials you know could seriously be of help. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

[Django Ajax forms](http://www.jonhill.ca/programming/ajax-forms-in-django)

[Dajax project](http://www.dajaxproject.com/multiply/)

[Ajax and Django views](http://brack3t.com/ajax-and-django-views.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you ask looks like implementing a RESTful API (create, update and get objects...)

You should have a look at [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org) or [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home)

For a comparison of those two look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430579/django-restful-api-django-piston-vs-django-tastypie)